# How to limit access to http://localhost/xampp/

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, htdocs

I installed `xampp` on a comupter (for example A) in a network, I set IP for `apache` so users in the network are able to access the `localhost`  on the machine A. I installed a web project in `htdocs` directory so users can see that page using `IP_OF_MACHINE/project`. the problem is they can see `IP_OF_MACHINE/xampp` or `IP_OF_MACHINE/phpmyadmin` page while I want them to be able to see only the `project` not other pages. How do I can achieve this?

Comment: You can do that by setting a password to XAMPP folder by accessing `http://localhost/security/index.php`

Comment: I did this but there was no option to set password for phpmyadmin, the password works only for xampp

Comment: This is because your `root` user have no password. When you set a  password for `root`, login screen will be shown for phpmyadmin too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a .htaccess file in the folders you don't want to be public and inside the .htaccess write the following :

```
order allow,deny
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all
```